# Wrong Review Audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

In my free time I like to review posts for users asking for the first time on Stack Overflow. while reviewing I failed an audit that I think it should not be the case.

On a side note: this is my first question here and based on my search on the site I believe this is the place to raise this issue please guide me if I am wrong

[This is the post I was reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26357808)

All I did is that I added a comment that have a link to [a guide on how to ask on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also I pointed out that he don't have to use uppercase.

But I got this message :

> STOP! Look and Listen.
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

It was instant so probably it is a system audit but I still think the question is not posted correctly so here I am posting it to know if my review was really bad and how to improve it. And if not what to do now to actually make the post better.

Comment: The question lacks an MCVE, so yes, it's a bad audit. It reacting like that to leaving a comment is unfortunately by design :rolling_eyes: I don't understand how a comment leads to a failed audit - even good posts can have improvement potential. That's just my two cents though. Anyway, I voted to close on the question

Comment: @Machavity thank you for the post, actually after reading your link, my post is a part of the problem the user in your post is trying to solve. so in a way yes it answers my question on a bigger scale. but i posted my question because i was not sure if my comment was in the right place or not. thank you for pointing the real reason behind it.

Comment: @Zoe thank you. one thing though, i don't have any experience in react so maybe the answers on that question is helping others, how about we try to tell the OP that he needs to edit his answer instead of closing it?. again im new to meta and i actually don't know how to contact the OP beside from comments.

Comment: I'm confused as to how it got "Viewed 2k times" with no action on it's open state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad audit since the system believes it to be a good post, but you commented as though it were a bad post, hence the system thinks that you weren't focusing.

Comment: okay took me couple of minutes to get it :p but i did. but we do agree that the system is wrong here right?

Comment: @George yes, I agree that the system was wrong.